# Cannot See Macros and Quick Text in Console App's Navigation Items

Tags: app, navigation, navigation-menu, lightning-app-manager

I've created a Console App. I need to add Macro and Quick Text to the Navigation items. I've added them from the App's setting from App Manager. But I cannot see them when I open navigation drop down in the app. However, I can edit the navigation items and add them from there. Thats not what I want. I want them to be present in the navigation items by default. The tabs for Macros and Quick Text are already present in the org. Could someone suggest what's missing here?

App Settings in App Manager:
[image: App Settings in App Manager]

Navigation Items:

[image: Navigation Items]

But I can personalize the navigation items by clicking edit button:

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a permission set to enable use of Macros.

1. In "Object Settings", select Tab "visible" checkbox.
2. Make sure that CRUD is assigned appropriately.
3. Click "Manage Assignment" button and add the user you want.
4. Refresh the page.